# Async Task vs Task

Tags: c#, multithreading, task

There is Async method `FuncAsync` and Task object t.
Both are doing same thing, both using the thread pool.
What's difference between these two strategies?

```
class Program
{
    private static async Task<int> FuncAsync(string str)
    {
        string s = await Task.Run(() =>
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0} <- Pooled?  ID -> {1}", Thread.CurrentThread.IsThreadPoolThread, Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
          //  Thread.Sleep(1000);
            return str;
        });
        return s.Length;

    }

    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Task<int> z = FuncAsync("Text");
        Console.WriteLine(z.Result);
        Task<int> t = Task.Run(() =>
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0} <- Pooled?  ID -> {1}", Thread.CurrentThread.IsThreadPoolThread, Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
            //  Thread.Sleep(1000);
            return "Text".ToString().Length;
        });
        Console.WriteLine(t.Result);
        Thread.CurrentThread.Join(1000);

        Console.ReadLine();

    }
}
```

I think that with Async method waiting Result and can not be close without finish task,
and with Task -  thread is background and may be closed without finish task.

Comment: Not much, except that you have anonymous method and more plumbing code in case of `Task`.

Comment: Sounds like you just need to go read an intro tutorial on `async/await`.

Comment: @Servy I Think so ))

Answer (score 0):

One is a reusable function, the other is not.  One passes the string *length* back across threads, the other passes the entire string.  Neither is actually running asynchronously because you are immediately asking for the `.Result` which blocks until the task completes (you should use `await` instead)

Comment: He can't use `await` inside `Main`.

Comment: True, but he shouldn't bother with Task.Run followed immediately by task.Result either :)

Comment: True... true :) I don't think his code has much meaning.